# Is it possible to pass arguments to the Application_Startup sub in outlook?

Tags: vba, command-line, outlook

I have a macro in outlook which I want to run on startup sometimes... Odd request I know. I know about the Application_Startup Sub but I am wondering if it is possible to pass command-line arguments to it?

EDIT: our real requirement is to sometimes run a macro on startup based on a command-line argument. I have tried VBS and Application.Run and also the command-line switch /autorun which has been deprecated as of outlook 2003.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GetCommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx) function which retrieves the command-line string for the current process. To access the function just paste this API declaration at the top of your macro module:

```
Declare Function GetCommandLineA Lib "Kernel32" () As String
```

And then in the VBA sub you can use the following code:

```
Dim cmdLineArgs As String

'Get the commande line string
cmdLineArgs = GetCommandLineA
```

Comment: I tried this and almost broke my outlook, was I doing something wrong? the code I wrote, took the command line arguments then showed a message box containing them. Will this break if there aren't any?

Comment: tried it in Word ... caused crash ... i read somewhere that win 64bit API is different ... found some code ... posted below ... works in win7 64

Answer (score 0):

found this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0017d844-3e4a-4115-bc51-cf02ca23db0c/vba-to-fetch-excel-command-line-64-bit?forum=exceldev

posted by : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/andreas%20killer/?ws=usercard-mini

```
'Note: Declaration is overloaded with LONG!
#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCommandLineL Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCommandLineA" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpyL Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlenL Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenA" (ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function GetCommandLineL Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCommandLineA" () As Long
Private Declare Function lstrcpyL Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function lstrlenL Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenA" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
#End If
'

Function GetCommandLine() As String

    #If Win64 Then
    Dim lngPtr As LongPtr
    #Else
    Dim lngPtr As Long
    #End If

    Dim strReturn As String
    Dim StringLength As Long

    lngPtr = GetCommandLineL                        ' Get the pointer to the commandline string
    StringLength = lstrlenL(lngPtr)                 ' get the length of the string (not including the terminating null character):
    strReturn = String$(StringLength + 1, 0)        ' initialize our string so it has enough characters including the null character:
    lstrcpyL strReturn, lngPtr                      ' copy the string we have a pointer to into our new string:
    GetCommandLine = Left$(strReturn, StringLength) ' now strip off the null character at the end:

End Function

Sub getCmdLine()

    Debug.Print GetCommandLine()

End Sub
```